# Magento 2.2 - combining js

Tags: admin, javascript, magento2.2

Has the combine js been moved from:

> Stores > Config > Advanced > Developer

All i currently get under **Advanced** is :

1. Admin
2. System

Tried switching different store views etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Thats correct because of **Deployment MODE** :  **Check your Deployment Mode it is in Production.**

To enable the developer tab menu under the Advanced You need to change it to **Developer Mode**

So run this command :  **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer**

Clear the cache by running this command : **php bin/magento cache:clean**

> Now check Go to admin ->logged in ->click on stores
>   ->configuration->advanced -> you will see developer option now.

Comment: Didn't think of checking the dev mode inside of mage. Thanks.

Comment: @andyjones Yes sometimes it happens , Anyways thanks Happy to help and keep helping :)

Comment: I have followed those exact instructions on Magento 2.2.5 (php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer, php bin/magento cache:clean), but the developer mode does not show under Advanced. Only Admin and System. I'm out of ideas how to get to Developer in the Admin, or do minify settings, etc. Any ideas?